# Problem in reading file from server using laravel excel

Tags: php, excel, laravel, laravel-excel

I am trying to read an excel file from server. I want to get the data and turn it into an array.

Earlier I tried converting excel into an array and I succeeded. I used the following code.

```
$data = Excel::toArray(new Import, request('file') , 'public');
```

My import Class was

```
class Import implements ToModel,WithCalculatedFormulas
{
    use Importable;
    /**
    * @param Collection $collection
    */
    public function model(array $row)
    {

    }
}
```

And it was working perfectly. Now instead of submitting the file by a form; I need to read it from server. So I changed the code to,

```
$data = Excel::toArray(new Import, $file_url , 'public');
```

But now it is giving me error like below. (I changed the url to post here)

> File not found at path:
>   http:/XXXX.YYY.com/temp_upload/1581488988_test.xlsx

I checked my server. The file is indeed there. Even, when I try to browse the URL it is downloading the correct file. But it isn't being read.

Comment: Use the system path to the file, not the HTTP URL.

Comment: I don't understand. Did you mean like "/public/temp_upload/.." ?

Comment: Anyway, I tried like "/public/temp_upload/..". Still not working. Same error is given.

Comment: Laravel have a builtin function `public_path()`, so use this function which returns the ***absolute*** system path to the folder/file in the `public` folder. Example: `public_path('temp_upload/.....')`